# Python | Find a specific line and save the two lines under it

Tags: python

sorry if the title confused you but what I'm looking for should be simple I think.

So basically I have a big text file that contains a list like this:

```
  From: United States, Chicago 2039 Street
  Name: Markus
  Code: 3294
```

It has thousands of lines that contain different cities, names and codes. What I'm trying to do is find every line that contains the word "Chicago" and I want it to save the two lines under it (Name and code) in a different text file.

I have this python code that saves the line that contains a specific word:

```
with open("names.txt", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f: #File that contains the names
with open("home.txt", "a", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f1: #Second file to save the info on
    for line in f:
        if str("Chicago") in line: #If line contains Chicago
            f1.write(str(line)) #Save the line in the second file
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if my name was "Kirby Chicago"? Do you need to account for that and only look for "Chicago" on certain lines?

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate your file using index and then fetch the next two indices when your desired line is found indexing gives you more control

```
with open("names.txt", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f: #File that contains the names
    lines = list(f)
    with open("home.txt", "a", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f1: #Second file to save the info on
        for index in range(len(lines)):
            if str("Chicago") in lines[index]: #If line contains Chicago
                f1.write(str(lines[index + 1])) #Save the line in the second file
                f1.write(str(lines[index + 2])) #Save the line in the second file
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` is an iterable and as such we can call `next()` on it to get the "next" two values.

```py
with open("names.txt", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f: #File that contains the names
    with open("home.txt", "a", encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f1: #Second file to save the info on
        for line in f:
            if str("Chicago") in line: #If line contains Chicago
                f1.write(next(f))
                f1.write(next(f))
```

Note that you might want to guard against running out of `f` via `next(f, None)` maybe.

If it was me, I would probably do:

```py
import contextlib
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    file_in = open('names.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8")
    file_out = open('home.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="")
    for from_line in file_in:
        name_line = next(file_in, None)
        code_line = next(file_in, None)
        if "Chicago" in from_line:
            file_out.write(name_line)
            file_out.write(code_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
extraLines = 0
for line in f:
        if extraLines or str("Chicago") in line : # Chicago line + 2 more
            f1.write(str(line)) #Save the line in the second file
            extraLines = (extraLines+1)%3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.find("Chicago") != -1: #If line contains Chicago
            f1.write(f[i + 1])
            f1.write(f[i + 2])
```